# How to write an Android application to do sysfs read/write.?

Tags: android, android-ndk, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, apk

I want to write an Android application with UI Button Read/Write that does **`sysfs read`** or **`sysfs write`**.

I found the below example code for java.io.RandomAccessFile.

```
    package com.tutorialspoint;

    import java.io.*;

    public class RandomAccessFileDemo {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {
             // create a new RandomAccessFile with filename test
             RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("c:/test.txt", "rw");

             // write something in the file
             raf.writeUTF("Hello World");

             // set the file pointer at 0 position
             raf.seek(0);

             // read the first byte and print it
             System.out.println("" + raf.read());

             // set the file pointer at 4rth position
             raf.seek(4);

             // read the first byte and print it
             System.out.println("" + raf.read());
          } catch (IOException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
          }

       }
    }
```

Can someone please tell me how to build this code using Android sdk.?

Comment: What do you have problems with? Writing Android apps? Creating buttons? Reading/writing files?

Comment: I am used to linux driver programming. I have exported sysfs to userspace. I wanted to access it in userspace android application. I am new to android application world. I don't want to start off with generalized link on writing android applications. It would be better if i get a template or skeleton stub to start off with my work

Comment: Please some one give pointers like .. where to start off for this application.

Comment: What do you need help with?  Opening a file?  Reading from the file?  That's all a "sysfs read" is from userspace.

Comment: Since I am new to android java application development. I need a simple android java application that lets me do the operation of what cat and echo lets us do from shell prompt.

Comment: Maybe `java.io.RandomAccessFile` is what you want?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Comment: @fadden I have edited my question in the top. please kindly comment on that.

Comment: @kzs Are you able to build anything yet for Android?  The question is a bit open-ended for a single answer.  Try looking at several of the YouTube tutorials on creating a hello android app.  You will need to grant permission to your app for writing to the file system.  That is done via an XML manifest.  Also download Eclipse and the Android plug-ins.  Try all of that and return with more specific questions.

Comment: @PeterL. I admit that my question is open ended :-) . I thought someone might have encountered same situation,solved and I might get the solution straight away. The solution which you have suggested is most welcome, I have to put some good time on it, which I don't have as of now. Let me see, I would try. thanks for the XML manifest info.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, make sure you have the permission to that sysfs node(Usually you don't, if you are developing a user app).

Secondly, I would say usually you don't have to talk to sysfs node directly from Android app.Below app there are Android Framework and HAL levels that did all the abstraction for you.

Since not sure about what you are going to do, here is an example I fetched from Android LightsService which directly talk to sysfs node, which might be helpful to you.

```
216        private static final String FLASHLIGHT_FILE = "/sys/class/leds/spotlight/brightness";
...
236        try {
237                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FLASHLIGHT_FILE);
238                byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
239                bytes[0] = (byte)(on ? '1' : '0');
240                bytes[1] = '\n';
241                fos.write(bytes);
242                fos.close();
243            } catch (Exception e) {
244                // fail silently
245            }
246        }
```

Comment: yeah. thanks for that. I wanted all the steps to create project in android sdk as well get an apk. would you mind to provide that too please.

Comment: @kzs I believe these kind of questions can be answered by Google, not here. See here `http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html`